# $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}, |A|<\infty\Rightarrow |B-A|\geq |B|-|A|,\ |\cdot|$ outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes, thanks.

"$A,B\subset\mathbb{R}, |A|<\infty\Rightarrow |B-A|\geq |B|-|A|$"

where $|\cdot|$ denotes outer measure.

My proof:

(1) countable subadditivity of outer measure; (2) outer measure preserves order

**(I)** $$|B|=|(B-A)\cup (A\cap B)|\overset{(1)}{\leq}|B-A|+|A\cap B|\Rightarrow |B-A|\geq |B|-|A\cap B|$$

**(II)** $$A\cap B\subset A\overset{(2)}{\Rightarrow} |A\cap B|\leq |A|\overset{\text{hyp.}}{<}\infty \Rightarrow -|A\cap B|\geq -|A|\overset{*}{\Rightarrow} |B|-|A\cap B|\geq |B|-|A|\overset{(I)}{\Rightarrow} \fbox{$|B-A|\geq |B|-|A|$}$$

*note that the following inequality is valid because $|A\cap B|<\infty$  otherwise we could have things like $\infty-\infty$ if $|B|=\infty$ or, if $|B|<\infty$ too, $-\infty\geq |B|-|A|\in\mathbb{R}$, absurd

Comment: +1 to your query for showing good work (in an area that I am not knowledgeable in, and therefore can't respond to).  Minor criticism : please include at least one english *word* (i.e. non-mathJax/non-Latex) in your title so that reviewers can right-click on the word to bring up your query.  I just edited your query title accordingly.

Comment: Low hanging fruit: you shouldn't write $A \cup A \cap B$ without parentheses, it's ambiguous.

Comment: @user2661923 corrected, thanks

Comment: @MikeF corrected, thanks

Comment: @lorenzo: still needs more brackets! :)

Comment: Perhaps a different approach: $|B-A|=\int \mathbb{1}_{B} - \mathbb{1}_{A} +  \mathbb{1}_{A \setminus B} > \int \mathbb{1}_{B} - \mathbb{1}_{A} = |B|-|A|$.

Comment: The assumption $|A| < \infty$ is key, so you should make sure to indicate where exactly in your proof you used it.

Comment: @MikeF I didn't use it, that's why I want my proof to be checked to see if it is nonetheless valid.

Comment: You used it when you subtracted $|A \cap B|$ from both sides of an inequality. It's only valid to do that with a finite quantity, so you should use $|A|<\infty$ to deduce $|A\cap B|<\infty$.

Comment: @MikeF Thanks! I have added a note to the proof to clarify that. By the way, if you deem my answer to be correct now, and would post your answer as a comment, I would gladly accept it

Comment: @Slugger: that might be a bit iffy here because the problem is about outer measure, so $A$ and $B$ don't need to be measurable. In my experience, it is a bit unusual to define integrals of nonmeasurable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edits, your solution looks pretty good and I have little in the ways of mathematical criticism to offer. I would just say that it is generally considered better style to write more words, fewer symbols and avoid "itemizing" the logical structure of your proof more than necessary. Basically, you want your proof to look more like an ordinary piece of prose, and less like computer code.

A solution more in keeping with these principles might look something like this:

> Because $B \subseteq B \cup A = (B-A) \cup A$, we have
> $$|B| \leq |(B-A) \cup A| \leq |B -A| + |A|.$$
> The first inequality above uses monotonicity of outer measure and the second uses subadditivity. Because $|A|<\infty$, we may subtract it on both sides to obtain the desired inequality:
> $$|B| - |A| \leq |B-A|.$$